# Get a list of Azure Servers in C#

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I need to fill a combobox with the servers of SQL available in the Azure portal. For example: I need to display the following list of servers in a combobox..

[image]

Have Azure some service for get this list of servers from C# code?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all servers from your Azure Subscriptions by using the Windows Azure Management Librairies (for ASM, Azure Service Management). Those librairies are wrappers around Azure Api and let you easily manage your ressources.

By using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql) SQL Management Library, you can retrieve all servers with a line of code :

```
using (SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(cred))
{
      var servers = await sqlManagementClient.Servers.ListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thibaut, Windows Azure Management Libraries(ASM) is a very easy way to get all SQL Azure servers in Azure portal. For get started with Windows Azure Management Libraries, Please have a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx). If you don't want to use this library, please try the SQL Database rest API to [get servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643936.aspx).